# Xampp MySQL tries to start and automatically stops

Tags: mysql, xampp

After doing this, Xampp tells me:

```
21:13:57  [main]    Control Panel Ready
21:14:06  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
21:14:06  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
21:14:12  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
21:14:12  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
21:14:12  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
21:14:12  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
21:14:12  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
21:14:12  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
21:14:12  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
21:14:12  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

So I ncheck the logs of the mysql and this is what it says:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-12-21 21:14:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-12-21 21:14:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-12-21 21:14:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-12-21 21:14:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-12-21 21:14:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-12-21 21:14:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-12-21 21:14:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-12-21 21:14:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-12-21 21:14:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-12-21 21:14:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-12-21 21:14:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-12-21 21:14:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-12-21 21:14:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.13 started; log sequence number 6331998436; transaction id 3576318
2020-12-21 21:14:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-12-21 21:14:11 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-12-21 21:14:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 201221 21:14:11
2020-12-21 21:14:11 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I haven't found a problem similar to my error logs, but maybe I missed that. I've seen different errors, but in this log, I can't even seem to figure out what the error is. Is it because of the file being full?(12MB as stated in the logs)

Earlier today, it did work but now all of a sudden not anymore. Does anyone know how to fix this and what's causing this?

Comment: Check your Windows Task Manager and Services.  It looks like MySQL is still running.  Stop them and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced the same issue and I just did this and it resolved that issue:

1. quit the XAMPP
2. cut the All files in C:\xampp\mysql\backup
3. paste and replace files in C:\xampp\mysql\data
4. run as administrator the XAMPP

Similar error log:
[image: Similar error log]

After following the steps above:

[image: after following the steps above]